# How to get MAC address of remote mobile device(mobile phone, tablet and so on)

Tags: android, ios, http, network-programming

For iphone, as far as I know, after IOS 7, can't get MAC address via SDK. For Android device, it seems I can get MAC address via API. But both of above need install a APP on device, and send the MAC back to server.

Is there any other method to get MAC address of remote device which can deploy easy?

Comment: Why do you want the MAC address? Note that Android M will be obscuring the MAC address for all apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a special requirement which need to get MAC of remote devices. Do you mean on Android M the API which used to get MAC address is suppressed？Is there any more details about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the MAC address, especially remotely.

MAC addresses get abstracted away at the physical layer, generally at the gateway/router.

You'll have to find another identifier. Try `identifierForVendor`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems source mac and destination mac both in Ethernet frame. Is there any method to get them out?